# Is there any way to verify with grunt that an application starts properly & then kill it?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm building a server and would like to verify that "node server.js" starts properly with a grunt task. Is there anyway to do this? Assuming that if there is no exit/error in 1 second that it starts properly and just kill it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I'll bake one for you... aaaand it's done. Here's [grunt-verify-app](https://github.com/bevacqua/grunt-verify-app)

Install

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-verify-app
```

Setup

```
grunt.initConfig({
    verify_app: {
        server: {
            options: {
                timeout: 10000,
                frequency: 1000,
                port: 3000,
                script: 'app
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Run

```
grunt verify_app:server
```

Profit

[image: verification.png]